# 3D transform image (in Bohemian Sketch)

Tags: iphone, image, 3d, transform

For my website, I want to use the vector image as shown here: http://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/226-iphone-5.html
It's an iPhone 5 that is tilted.

Now I need to add my image to the screen which means I need to 3D-tilt it. I've tried and searched a lot but couldn't figure out how to transform my image so that it fits the iPhone 5 screen.

Any help in guiding me how to 3D transform my image would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Frank

Comment: Any ideas on this? I'm looking to do the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

I recently released a plugin solving the exact issue, it allows you to draw a shape with the Vector tool and then apply the content of an artboard into the area. It's called Magic Mirror, please take a look at http://magicmirror.design